# How do I remotely access/play on a docker Minecraft server created by Kitematic?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, port-forwarding, docker, minecraft

I want to play on my Minecraft server using my laptop, no matter where I'm at. The server is a docker Minecraft server created by Kitematic located on a dedicated home server with Windows 10.

I followed [this](https://blog.docker.com/2015/06/minecraft-server-docker-1/) blog post. At the end it says

> Next Steps – Deploying Your Minecraft Server - In our next post, we will discuss how you can deploy the Minecraft server created through Kitematic to the cloud so you can enjoy the game with your family and friends!

However, there is no part 2 as far as I can tell.

Here's what I did:

1. Installed docker toolkit for Windows (on Windows 10).
2. Opened Kitematic, which came with the installation, and clicked "Create" next to the Minecraft server image.
3. After spinning up a container it tells me the docker port is `25565/tcp` and **the Access Url is `192.168.99.100:32781`**
4. Ran the command `docker ps` and it gives me:

   `CONTAINER ID 7d80b0a2d5f1 
   IMAGE kitematic/minecraft:latest
   COMMAND "/bin/sh -c 'echo eul"
   CREATED 9 minutes ago
   STATUS Up 5 minutes
   PORTS 0.0.0.0:32778->25565/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32781->25565/tcp
   NAMES minecraft`

I want to use Minecraft to access this server from other computers on the same network as well as external networks so I can play with friends. Currently Minecraft can't find the server even when I'm connected to the same network.

I assume I need to do some sort of port forwarding, as well as some binding or something from the docker container to a port on the host. Maybe Virtualbox needs some setting. I've tried several things but to no avail.

So how do I remotely access/play on this server?

NOTES:

- I've verified that the eula.txt is set to true.
- Pinging 192.168.99.100 from the container's host machine works, which is the ip of the default docker vm.

Comment: The Docker port forwarding is already active. You don't describe, however, how the Docker VM's networking is set up.

Comment: Do I need to set up the port forwarding in my physical router? If so, what are the internal & external ports?
How do I check the Docker VM's networking set up? I just installed Docker Tools which installed Virtulabox and Kitematic automatically. All the defaults settings are in place.